# Hide rows based on Multiple column value if count is 0 with argument in function

Tags: excel, vba

I need a function where I'm passing filtered range of data as an argument in `HideRangeIfEmpty` function. However, my code hides all the rows which are empty in the loop.

The expected output should be the row has to be hidden only if count of filtered visible data count (example G5, T5, AG5 is zero) is Zero.

```
Case "UsGe"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Range("F:BC").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Range("G:G,T:T,AG:AG").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Range("a1").Select
Call HideRangeIfEmpty("G6:AG200")

Private Sub HideRangeIfEmpty(R1)
For Each xRg In Range(R1)
    If xRg.Value = "" Then
      xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
     Else
      xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
   Next xRg
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can address the relevant columns as separate areas by giving them as multi range:

```
Private Sub UsGe()
    ' ...
    Call HideRangeIfEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("G6:G200, T6:T200, AG6:AG200"))
End Sub
```

If any of the column's value is <> "", then the row will be shown, otherwise not:

```
Private Sub HideRangeIfEmpty(ByRef r As Range)
    Dim CurrentRow As Long, CurrentArea As Long, CurrentColumn As Long
    Dim ToBeShown As Boolean

    ' Check each row (defined by the first area)
    For CurrentRow = 1 To r.Areas(1).Rows.Count

        ToBeShown = False   ' default: not hidden

        ' check each area (one or more columns)
        For CurrentArea = 1 To r.Areas.Count

            ' check cell in each column
            For CurrentColumn = 1 To r.Areas(CurrentArea).Columns.Count

                ' If any has a value, then set the marker
                If r.Areas(CurrentArea).Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentColumn) <> "" Then _
                    ToBeShown = True
            Next CurrentColumn
        Next CurrentArea

        ' show complete row, if marker is set
        r.Areas(1).Cells(CurrentRow, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = Not ToBeShown
    Next CurrentRow
End Sub
```

Now it also works with ranges like "G6:I200", where my code will check column G, H and I then.

Comment: No Luck, its hiding a row even if  there is value in G6 cell.

(G6 has a value, T6 and AG6 does'nt have any So the row should be visible)

Comment: Now I changed it, that the rows are shown, if any of the column values is <> ““. If it works, please consider to mark it as answer.